# How to preserve aspect ratio of VectorDrawable?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have been trying to create a splash screen for an Android app as described at 
[Splash Screens the Right Way | Big Nerd Ranch](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) with a style

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

The background_splash looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sparrow"/>
</layer-list>
```

And sparrow.xml looks like

```
<vector android:height="240dp"
    android:width="240dp"
    android:viewportHeight="512.0"
    android:viewportWidth="512.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#e000"
        android:pathData="M407.2,55.2c-20.8,2.4 -42.9,16.8 -65.6,42.7 -4.5,5.1, lot of data here ,-8.2z" android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#cc0000"
        android:pathData="M474,98.9c-12.6,3.9 -17.8,15.3 -12.4,26.8 1.4,2.8 3.1,5.4 3.9,5.7 1.3,0.5 11.4,-0.5 20.5,-1.9 1.4,-0.2 5,-0.6 8,-1 8,-0.8 11.1,-1.6 10.8,-2.5 -0.3,-0.7 -5.1,-6.4 -21.4,-25.3 -2.4,-2.7 -4.7,-3.2 -9.4,-1.8z" android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
</vector>
```

However, the issue that I am seeing is that aspect ratio of 1:1 as defined by width and height properties of `vector` is not maintained when it is displayed on the device screen. For example, a circle is displayed as follows in the android studio

[image: in android studio]

However, the above image is displayed as follows on the device as it takes over all the available height available to it.

[image: on device]

Comment: What does "not being maintained" mean exactly?

Comment: This problem exists in some earlier versions of Android (in my Sumsung Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0.1). But in the latest emulator image it was fixed. Didn't tested in other devices.